# How to measure output of a piezoelectric?

Tags: power-supply, noise, oscilloscope, piezo

I have a (perhaps trivial) question that is buzzing me a bit these days. A brief explanation of the project: I have metallic plate with two piezoelectric sensors attached on each side. One is used as transmitter (TX), other as receiver (RX). I am driving TX with function generator and high voltage amplifier. On RX I am trying to measure the output (see the waveform).

Now, problem is the following: When I am measuring with oscilloscope, it picks up the noise from the power supply, which is generated by the amplifier (noise is exactly the same shape as input signal into TX piezo). I have tried using power transformer to get rid of the dirty ground, but it doesn't change a thing. I know I have to create some 'buffer circuit' between RX and oscilloscope and have some ideas, but would also appreciate your ideas/suggestions, not to spend too much time on this problem.

Here's the circuit I have thought of:

[image: Circuit]

INA stands for instrumentation amplifier (classic schematic with three op-amps), lower part is an averager. I would measure with oscilloscope between the two output on the schematic.

Any ideas/thoughts are welcome.

Comment: What exactly is the supply? It would seem that the problem sits there and not in your analog circuit? Is it 50Hz line noise or something else? Spontaneously it sounds like you should use a LDO voltage ref circuit to supply the analog parts.

Comment: Of course, all components of RX circuit will be supplied with LDO regulators. 

I want to transmit a signal with acoustic wave. I excite TX transducer (using signal generator and amplifier) with some sine burst. When measuring output of RX this same shaped burst appears on oscilloscope because it is transmitted through the power line (same power line that powers amplifier and oscilloscope). I hope I made it clearer.

Comment: Rori, still unclear. TX is driven with a number of cycles at piezo's resonant frequency, then not driven (becomes open-circuit?). During this TX burst, expect that RX will produce similar output at lower amplitude, due to acoustic coupling between TX and RX transducers. Almost impossible to avoid this coupling. What makes you conclude that coupling is via power lines?

Comment: Any signal generated to the "right" of the LDO wouldn't be ringing back into the mains voltage or something is terribly wrong. Maybe you have simply grounded your scope probes poorly? Make sure to ground them as close to the op amps as possible. Alternatively, I suppose you could also have ground layout problems.

Comment: To eliminate noise from the power supply - if this is actually the problem - my first thought is to add a sequence of LC filters

Comment: Can you post an oscilloscope image showing the transmit pulse on one scope channel and the receive signal on the other scope channel? Also, what is the thickness of your sample and what frequency are you transmitting and what is the specified operational frequency of the transmit transducer? Also, what is the intent of your lower opamp circuit?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is acoustic feedback from the transmitting sensor to the receiving sensor. All active sonars have this characteristic. That is why naval sonars blank their receivers during the transmit time and some time thereafter to avoid overloading the receive preamps from the direct transmission and subsequent reverberation. It is very difficult to avoid this problem since the transmission level is so much greater than the expected receive level since the latter generally has a large transmission path loss plus a reflection loss. However, unless your target is very close in range. the time delay between transmission and reception will allow you to gate out the unwanted signals.

Comment: Any idea how they implement (concept) of blanking the receivers?